# Uploading files via Dropbox/Google - Should I change the UI?

Tags: gui-design, branding, uploading-documents

I am currently working on the user journey for job applications on mobile devices. The big task to tackle is how the user uploads a CV/resume file (usually word or PDF).

The option to upload from Dropbox/G drive is proven quite popular for us. But the UI has been changed to reflect our branding rather than the typical brand UI that you see from Dropbox or G Drive.

I was wondering if there is any findings out there to suggest that this is a good or bad thing. Or some solid opinion in order for a decision to be made on this.

I look forward to you responses.

Dan

Comment: Does the Dropbox/G Drive UI open in a modal or new window or is integrated directly into the page?

Also do you have any screenshots of your specific implementation? It may be easier to give advice with a better understanding of what you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I don't have any specific research in mind. I believe that the expectation from most users when using a third party integration within a website or web app would be to see the UI of the third party if the integration were within a modal or new window (e.g. Facebook/Twitter login/authentication).

If the integration were on the page, it would be wise to use the third party's logo (e.g. Dropbox, Google Drive) and a clear explanation that you will be accessing files from their account on that service so the user understands exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going with actual UI rather than branding UI as the user is habituated to use them that way and seeing a different screen might confuse him.

- it will make him conscious all of sudden and he might backtrack to confirm
- and it will also make him doubt the authenticity of app.